# Invalid Signature with telesign call REST API

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

The API sends a verification code via a phone call that the user then enters into a website... basically verifying that there phone number is valid.

But I'm having trouble signing the request. No matter what I try it returns "Invalid Signature"

The API documentation:
http://docs.telesign.com/rest/content/verify-call.html

The authentication documentation:
http://docs.telesign.com/rest/content/rest-auth.html

The authentication examples:
http://docs.telesign.com/rest/content/auth-examples.html

The code:

```
<cffunction name="encryptHmacSHA1" returntype="binary" access="public" output="false">
    <cfargument name="base64Key" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="signMessage" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="encoding" type="string" default="UTF-8">

    <cfset var messageBytes = JavaCast("string",arguments.signMessage).getBytes(arguments.encoding)>
    <cfset var keyBytes = binaryDecode(arguments.base64Key, "base64")>
    <cfset var key  = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec")>
    <cfset var mac  = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac")>
    <cfset key  = key.init(keyBytes,"HmacSHA1")>
    <cfset mac  = mac.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm())>
    <cfset mac.init(key)>
    <cfset mac.update(messageBytes)>

    <cfreturn mac.doFinal()>
</cffunction>


<cfscript>
    // PHONE NUMBER TO CALL
    phoneNumberToCall = "15554565555"; 

    // KEYS
    keys = structNew();
    keys.customerID = "D561FCF4-BA8D-4DFC-86D1-1A46DF47A308";
    keys.apiKey = "mDzGHsMOc2g/ivkuINEFVh6fn/v4kdjvlTvtgFVOShu7hVWXS0eV2nLSw1FXgEzDSuOjhlKLXvneiq+YFG1/Vg==";

    // DATES
    dates = structNew();
    dates.timeZoneInfo = GetTimeZoneInfo();
    dates.dateToUse = DateAdd("h",dates.timeZoneInfo.utcHourOffset,now());
    dates.signingDate = DateFormat(dates.dateToUse,"ddd, dd mmm yyyy") & " " & TimeFormat(dates.dateToUse,"HH:mm:ss") & " +0000";


    // HEADERS
    headers = [ 
           "POST",
           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
           "#dates.signingDate#",
           "phone_number=#phoneNumberToCall#&ucid=OTHR", 
           "/v1/verify/call"
          ];

    headerText = arrayToList(headers, chr(10)) & chr(10);

    // CREATE SIGNATURE
    stringToSign = binaryEncode( encryptHmacSHA1(keys.apiKey, headerText), "base64");

    // AUTHORIZE HEADER
    Authorization = "TSA" & " " & keys.customerID & ":" & stringToSign;
</cfscript>

<cfhttp method="POST" url="https://rest.telesign.com/v1/verify/call" port="443" charset="UTF-8" result="verifyPhoneCall"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="authorization" value="#Authorization#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="date" value="#dates.signingDate#">
    <cfhttpparam name="phone_number" value="#phoneNumberToCall#" type="formfield">
    <cfhttpparam name="ucid" value="OTHR" type="formfield">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#verifyPhoneCall#">
```

The headers need to be included in the signature with "new lines". And the docs also say that they need to be in the same order that the http tag is sending them in. I don't think I have the order correct... or even how I'm supposed to set an order in the cfhttp call.

Any help is appreciated. And yes the keys are real. I'll generate new ones soon.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: I'm hoping the credentials you posted is not valid anymore, because it can be easily abused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over their documentation on [Constructing the CanonicalizedPOSTVariables Element](http://docs.telesign.com/rest/content/canonicalization.html#constructing-the-canonicalizedpostvariables-element) it mentions that the POST body must match the string used when constructing the signature (emphasis mine):

> ... when you construct the signature string, you must use the body of
>   the POST request **exactly** as it is delivered to the service.

By default, `cfhttpparam` url encodes any `formField` values. Since you are *not* encoding those values when you construct the signature, the content submitted by cfhttp does not match. Hence the error.

Either disable automatic encoding for all of the form fields in the signature:

```
   <cfhttpparam name="phone_number" 
         value="#phoneNumberToCall#"
         type="formfield"  
         encoded="false">
```

... or use type="body" instead. Then you have complete control over the post content:

```
   <cfhttpparam type="body" 
       value="phone_number=15554565555&ucid=OTHR">
```

**Update:**

Also, get rid of the final new line ie chr(10) in the "headerText". Otherwise your cfhttp content still will not match the signature. ie Use this:

```
headerText = arrayToList(headers, chr(10));
```

.. instead of:

```
headerText = arrayToList(headers, chr(10)) & chr(10);
```

Comment: BTW, CF10 has an [hmac() function](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/HMac) built in. So you could use that instead of the custom udf. But get things code working first :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explaining the problem/solution. I really appreciate it. I'll look into hmac()... and get the new keys.